# Dockerized .net 8 app doesn't expose port correctly

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm trying to dockerize a dotnet 8 web api project.
I'm on Windows 10 with Docker Desktop installed.

This is the Dockerfile I'm using

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the built application from the build image
COPY ./bin/Release/net8.0/ /app

# Expose the port the app will run on
EXPOSE 5000

# Set the environment variable for ASP.NET Core
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

# Set the entry point for the application
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Finch.Agents.dll"]
```

This is the launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60197",
      "sslPort": 44302
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7120;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this the docker-compose.yml part with which I run the container

```
  finch-agent:
    image: finch-agent:1.0.0
    container_name: finch-agent
    ports:
      - "8081:5000"
```

Below is the `docker logs ...`

```
---------------------------------------------
.... my logs ...
---------------------------------------------
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[15]
      Overriding HTTP_PORTS '8080' and HTTPS_PORTS ''. Binding to values defined by URLS instead 'http://+:5000'.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

between the `-----` lines appears some custom log messages I printed, so I'm sure the application is running.
Besides, it seems that the application is correctly listening on port 80.

Why, then, if I open the browser at http://localhost:8081/swagger I get a 404 ERROR? (I also get the same error at http://localhost:8081/)

PS: 'm also sure that the application works correcly when running with `dotnet run`, not dockerized.

**edit**:

additional information: Following thepip3r comments, I add the following information:

results of `netstat -anop`

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name     Timer
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:35509        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                    off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/dotnet             off (0.00/0/0)
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:38653        0.0.0.0:*                           -                    off (0.00/0/0)
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     47244    1/dotnet             /tmp/dotnet-diagnostic-1-156353-socket
```

Concerning general and security settings for Docker Desktop, I can add that other containers exposing web apps (not dotnet, eg. I've got a phpmyadmin container running witht he same docker-compsoe), work correctly.

Comment: Assuming "http://localhost:8081" is from the docker computer.  Have you exec'd into the container and ensured the application is listening properly (correct port, etc.)?  netstat -anop.  You should also be able to run the same command from the machine running docker and see port 5000 open.

Comment: yes, localhost is the docker computer. 
netstat -anop includes the following, It seems that 5000 is there but I'm not sure what to do with this then:
4

`...
 tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/dotnet             off (0.00/0/0)
 ...`

Comment: all that's saying is that there's a listener for ipv6 traffic on localhost for port 5000.  Do you have a host-based firewall you could temporarily disable to test?  When I'm building containers (always Linux tho), there always seem be the "usual suspects", from inside out:  if you exec into the container, can you netstat -anop to see an application holding open the expected socket?  Can you see the listener on the "docker host"?  Does the config match between?  Is there a security product blocking?  Then I'll use curl/telnet, etc. to test connectivity soup-to-nuts.

Comment: I've updated the question with additional information and  the whole netstat -anop output. using `curl http://localhost:5000/swagger` even inside the container (in docker exec) gives a 404.

Comment: Wait... the "edit" you added appears from inside your container -- you only have 5000 listening on the ipv6 interface.  if you're wanting it on IPv4 then you need to bind your app to to 5000 on the IPv4 interface as well.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET 8.0 Microsoft has changed Dockerfile which now use 8080 and 8081 ports. So you must use these port for accessing your ASP.NET Core app on Docker container. This working example - [Multi-Container ASP.NET Core App with Docker Compose](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-compose-aspnet-core/) is based on .NET 8.0 version and will help you to make changes.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the following line into the Dockerfile

> ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS 80

Comment: This needs an `=`!
Like `ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80`

Otherwise I like this answer. The use of the newly introduced `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` is even encouraged in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port
The solution is especially helpful, if you always want the same port exposed in docker; irrespective of environments like "Testing", "Staging", or "Production".